# Is it okay to unlink files without closing them in ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux, file

Is it safe to unlink a file in ruby in Linux without closing it first? Does it matter?

Comment: On linux I'd say this is perfectly legal since you *can* delete a file without closing it. It's used for example to create undiscoverable temps files.

Comment: It depends on the *operating system*. On Posix system (and Linux) it is acceptable (and a common practice to get really temporary files). I heard that it is disallowed on Windows (you cannot remove an opened file), but I know nothing about Windows.

Comment: Ruby provides really convenient means for opening, modifying, and then closing a file all in one go; rarely if ever should your Ruby code have any hanging file handles.

Answer (score 4):

On linux this is safe and is often used to create *undiscoverable* temporary files.

You can read and write from and to the file as long as you have it opened, whether it was deleted or not is irrelevant. The file will truly disappear when you close it AND delete it, no matter the order.

Comment: But does Ruby actually do this, or does it close the file before deleting it?

Comment: @nitro2k01 Ruby does not close the file when you `unlink` it, it just issues an `unlink` system call.

Comment: It must be noted that you can still discover them if you examine `/proc/$PID/fd` directory while the file is open

Comment: I think it is more about not having to explicitly clean up after yourself than other processes not being able to find your temp file.